# How to test single application (not project) in Django?

Tags: django, testing

I would like to test my small application, that I keep in a separate package. Right now I created a "test_project" directory, created a test project there and I am using the project's manage.py to run tests. But I keep wondering - is there a better method? Is it possible to launch a single app's tests, perhaps with some default configuration (like, sqlite database)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is possible to run a single app's tests standalone, without creating a Django test project for that purpose. One way of doing so is by creating a `runtests.py` in your app's root dir which setups Django settings and runs `./manage.py test your_app` programmatically. One example of `runtests.py` is Django's own: [runtests.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/tests/runtests.py) ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/unit-tests/)).

Django's own `runtests.py` is a good reference but I find it convoluted for most cases. Below are a couple of alternative examples:

- [Django-Modeltranslation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation/blob/master/runtests.py)
- [My own minimalistic one](https://github.com/dmarcelino/django-sameas/blob/b6a6d8bfaf7f4b1398ad778c620260f2efd970a2/runtests.py)

Comment: You have my upvote and I marked it as an accepted answer. I'd really like you to add information, since what version of Django that ``runtests.py`` thing is supported. Is it new?

Comment: @dotz, that's a very interesting question, one I didn't know the answer but couldn't resist looking for it. As far as I can see Django's `runtests.py` was created in 2005 and is available since v1.0. Here's the original commit: https://github.com/django/django/commit/daf8467b37f7aaae0b463b40a2c9d98f1f53c556#diff-bf0d7f89b37ba018fb5c5b2833b37dd3

Answer (score 13):

Writing this down because I don't see it on here yet

[From the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/overview/)

If your django structure looks something like this as it should:

```
Project dir/
    /myapp
    /myotherapp
    /myproject
```

Django allows you to execute test from only "myotherapp" by executing:

```
./manage.py test myotherapp/
```

This will execute all test under "myotherapp" whereas

```
./manage.py test
```

will execute all test in your projects directory.

Comment: @AmgedRustom why? It does not address OP's case, who keeps the app he wants to test as a separate (probably pip-installed) package somewhere in `site-packages`, as far as I understand.

Comment: @Chris I think it's the correct answer because although OP said it's a separate package; it still is a Django app. So it should be tested using Django.

Comment: I wanted to test a separate package without creating a test project first. From what I see, it's still not obvious or documented.

Answer (score 7):

If you use nose you can run a single app's tests.

`python manage.py test app.tests:TestClassHere`

as for testing a single app.  I just follow the convention other big django projects do, and that is exactly what you are doing.  Create a test_project directory.

https://github.com/mozilla/django-piston/tree/master/tests/test_project

I figure if it is good enough for some of the biggest django pluggable apps it's good enough for me.

Comment: Thank you, for a very long time this was the accepted answer as it was the best one. Currently I think that this one by Dario is better. Thanks for being the accepted answer for about 5 years or so.

Answer (score 2):

Ofcourse you *can* test the Python parts with a standalone unittest if you don't need any django dependencies

A Django environment requires atleast a **settings.py** and **manage.py** file. You can setup those with essential stuff only and UnitTest your app with manage.py. You should see a project as a Django runtime environment, there's no Django without it. You can probably mimic settings but tbh you would just be creating more hacks than simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a custom test runner and override the path it searches for tests in.

Perhaps I buried the lede here. I recently inherited a project that had legacy tests they wanted to keep for historical reasons, so I was forced to write all my tests in one folder and point to it

```
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner


class MyTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'top_level': str(settings.TEST_DISCOVER_TOP_LEVEL)})
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def run_tests(self, test_labels, extra_tests=None, **kwargs):
        # In order to override the top_level directory, the test_label must match the top_level
        kwargs.update({'test_labels': [str(settings.TEST_DISCOVER_TOP_LEVEL)]})
        return super().run_tests(extra_tests=extra_tests, **kwargs)
```

and in your settings

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'path.to.my.module.MyTestRunner'

TEST_DISCOVER_TOP_LEVEL = BASE_DIR / 'tests/unit_and_integration_tests'
```