# What is the purpose of third-party, reusable django app tests for the app consumer?

Tags: django, testing

I've been using Django for under a year and would like clarification on the role of tests within a reusable django app.  Popular apps, for example, like django-allauth  - https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth - come with tests.  From the point of view of the app consumer what is the purpose of these tests?  I can see when I run -

```
python manage.py test
```

That only MY tests are executed and not the app tests.

Furthermore when I did run the tests -

```
python manage.py test allauth.account
```

Pretty much everything failed.  For example the first test failed because allauth tried to create a user object with a keyword 'username' which isn't how my project user model is configured (I just have an email field).  So these tests which all-auth provides are supposed to run within which project exactly?  I'd have thought app designers should create tests which accommodate any proper app consumer project config.  That way running the tests informs you whether or not your project is correctly integrated from the consumed apps point of view.

I noticed a similar question but it doesn't really help with my more general question - 
[How to test single application (not project) in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897090/how-to-test-single-application-not-project-in-django)

By the way I've checked my project config for consuming the all-auth app and it does have the right config. As per - https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-user-models, for a user model with a unique email and no username i have -

```
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
```

**

On reflection I guess it is not possible for the app designer to write such tests.  For example the User model must have a REQUIRED_FIELDS property.  The app designer can't know how to populate the project user model based on this property.

So am i right in thinking app tests are only for the app designer?  I ask because I'm trying to write my first reusable app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a continuous integration logic: the app test are included in the package to validate that the package is running as expected. As the end user you don't have to run those, because it's already done, usually by Travis, when the package is built/pushed to pypi.

You usually have a nice coverage icon with the % of code covered by the test in the readme of the repo. You'll also have a build on python 3.x and Django 2.x 3.x when available. That's usually done using tox which allow to run the tests on multiple setup while a ./manage.py test will only validate on the current setup.

I won't be too concerned by the fact that the tests aren't running on your specific use case, because the app test are here to validate the package on a "clean" Django install, so the fact that the test isn't running with a email User is normal. There's no reason to make it work on such a user at the app level, unless defining user by email without a login is a feature of the package.

What you are talking about when you say "I'd have thought app designers should create tests which accommodate any proper app" is basically impossible, because something like the User can be defined in 1000 ways. Furthermore it won't be unit tests anymore. This will be integration test, which isn't the responsibility of the app devs. They don't integrate the application, that's the consumer who's doing it and should do its own integration test depending on its use case.

If you want to read more about this I would suggest googling unit tests vs integration tests vs end to end tests.

Comment: Just looked at allauth, it uses a custom function to get the user model and the classical `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model` method, so it should work with most of the User models.

Comment: Yes I see what you are saying about the impossibility of the app taking into consideration all app configs.  I realized this with the question update I submitted.  Do you know of any nice tutorials which talk through publishing an app which includes the tox file and travis?

Comment: There's a lot of nice ressources on pypi. You can also look at this post: https://towardsdatascience.com/extensive-python-testing-on-travis-ci-4c24db9bf961

Comment: And even if it's atlassian oriented, I found the posts they made on CI/CD very well done : https://www.atlassian.com/continuous-delivery/continuous-integration/how-to-get-to-continuous-integration